# Find products not being purchased

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble finding an optimal solution for this issue:

I have 2 tables, test_a and test_b.

Test_a stores details of customer buying products.

Test_b is basically a product table which lists products I would like to track. Customers may buy many products but not all products are in test_b, only the products I would like to track are in test_b.

I would like to track which products each individual customers do not buy.

A simplified table of test_a and test_b will look like this:

test_a

[image]

Test_b

[image]

I have tried this statement:

```
select * from test_a a
right outer join test_b b
on trim(a.product) = trim(b.product)
```

The statement above only tells me which product no customer bought at all but does not tell me which product each particular customer does not buy. I would like the result to show the date of purchase of that product being blank for a particular customer not buying that product, if they bought the product, then the dateofpurchase field is the actual date of purchase.

*** Update

The result I would like to see is:

[image]

Is there a clean and efficient way to achieve the goal stated above? One approach I can think of may be doing the full outer join and then filter out the products not in test_b but this does not seem to be very efficient. My real test_a table has a couple of millions records and the test_b contains close to thousand records.

Attached is the script of the sample tables I mentioned above:

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEST_A" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "CUSTOMER" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "PRODUCT" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "DATEOFPURCHASE" DATE
   ) ;
Insert into  TEST_A (ID,CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,DATEOFPURCHASE) values (1,'A ','P1',to_date('12-DEC-19','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into  TEST_A (ID,CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,DATEOFPURCHASE) values (2,'A ','P2',to_date('01-NOV-17','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into  TEST_A (ID,CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,DATEOFPURCHASE) values (3,'A ','P3',to_date('01-JAN-20','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into  TEST_A (ID,CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,DATEOFPURCHASE) values (4,'A ','P4',to_date('15-JUL-15','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into  TEST_A (ID,CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,DATEOFPURCHASE) values (5,'B','P1',to_date('01-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into  TEST_A (ID,CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,DATEOFPURCHASE) values (6,'B','P3',to_date('12-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into  TEST_A (ID,CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,DATEOFPURCHASE) values (7,'C','P3',to_date('15-JUN-12','DD-MON-RR'));


  CREATE TABLE "TEST_B" 
   (    "PRODUCT" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "DEPARTMENT" NUMBER(3,0)
   ) ;
Insert into TEST_B (PRODUCT,DEPARTMENT) values ('P1',1);
Insert into TEST_B (PRODUCT,DEPARTMENT) values ('P2',2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns desired result, but ... I don't like it much.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select distinct y.customer, b.product, x.dateofpurchase
  2  from test_b b cross join (select a.customer
  3                            from test_a a
  4                            where a.product in (select b.product from test_b b)
  5                           ) y
  6  left join test_a x on x.customer = y.customer and x.product = b.product
  7  order by y.customer, b.product;

CUSTOMER                   PRODUCT                    DATEOFPURC
-------------------------- -------------------------- ----------
A                          P1                         12.12.2019
A                          P2                         01.11.2017
B                          P1                         01.04.2016
B                          P2

SQL>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much... I knew that it needs to be some combination of cross join and outer join but I can not wrap my head around it. Your solution is clean, clear and effective!! Thank you so much for coming to my rescue! :) Very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes it does! It may take a little time for processing due to the amount of existing data I have, but this is the best solution I got so far and most importantly it works!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `left join` over `right join`, but what you need is a `where` clause to find the non-matches:

```
select b.*   -- why bring in columns from a when you know they are all NULL?
from test_b b left join
     test_a a
     on a.product = b.product
where a.product is null;
```

I removed the `trim()`.  You would only need that if your data is dirty and you don't have properly declared foreign key relationships.

Personally, I prefer `not exists` for this:

```
select b.*
from test_b b
where not exists (select 1 from test_a a where a.product = b.product);
```

EDIT:

If you want this *per customer*, then do a `cross join` of customers and products to get all combinations of the two.  Then remove the ones that exist:

```
select c.customer, b.product
from (select distinct customer from test_a) c cross join
     test_b b left join
     test_a a
     on a.customer = c.customer and a.product = b.product
where a.customer is null;  -- no match
```

Comment: thanks for looking into it. However, your suggestion does not seems to yield what I am looking for. I would like to see for each and every customer, which product they do not buy.. maybe I question was not clear... let me update the question

Comment: @user1205746 . . . Ahhh, that's what you mean by "each individual customers do not buy".

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. My apologies for not being clear. English is my second language...

Comment: @user1205746 . . . One learns a lot from seeing other people's interpretations.  My initial read focused on the plural, so I simplified it to "customer who do not buy", but I see what you intended now.

Answer (score 0):

This PIVOT can be used to see what customers have purchased what products

```
select *
  from (
select customer, product
  from test_a )
  pivot
  ( count(*)
    for product in ('P1', 'P2', 'P3')
  );
```